# BuildWindowCore error when hosting a window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to host a window of another process in my process.
To do so I'm using `HwndHost` like this:

```
public class MyHandle : HwndHost
{
    #region User32.dll

    private static Int32 WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
    private static Int32 WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
    private static Int32 WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;
    private static Int32 GWL_STYLE = -16;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr procid);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndParent);
    #endregion
    private Action WindowCoreBuilt = null;

    private IntPtr m_window = IntPtr.Zero;

    public MyHandle(IntPtr window, Action windowCoreBuiltDelegate)
    {
        m_window = window;
        WindowCoreBuilt = windowCoreBuiltDelegate;
    }

    protected override System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef BuildWindowCore(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hwndParent)
    {
        int guestStyle = SetWindowLong(m_window, GWL_STYLE, WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE);
        SetParent(m_window, hwndParent.Handle);

        HandleRef hwnd = new HandleRef(this, m_window);
        InvokeHelper.InvokeDelegate(this.Dispatcher, () => WindowCoreBuilt());
        return hwnd;
    }

    protected override void DestroyWindowCore(HandleRef hwnd)
    {
    }
}
```

It usually works, but sometimes I get an exception like this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: BuildWindowCore failed to return the hosted child window handle.
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildWindow(HandleRef hwndParent)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildOrReparentWindow()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.OnSourceChanged(Object sender, SourceChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.SourceChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.PresentationSource.UpdateSourceOfElement(DependencyObject doTarget, DependencyObject doAncestor, DependencyObject doOldParent)
   at System.Windows.PresentationSource.OnVisualAncestorChanged(DependencyObject uie, AncestorChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnVisualAncestorChanged(Object sender, AncestorChangedEventArgs e)
```

The stacktrace goes much deeper, but I don't think it's relevant.
My questions are:
1. What could cause this and how can I fix it?
2. How can I catch this exception to prevent my application from crashing?   (It happens in a system thread that I don't have access to...)

Answer (score 1):

```
_hwnd = BuildWindowCore(hwndParent);

if(_hwnd.Handle == IntPtr.Zero || !UnsafeNativeMethods.IsWindow(_hwnd))
{
     throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.ChildWindowNotCreated));
}
```

This is specific part of [WPF source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=HostedWindowMustBeAChildWindow) that throws the exception. `IsWindow` is direct invoke of [Win32 IsWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

My guess is that you are somehow returning `IntPtr.Zero` handle from `BuildWindowCore`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the host control content to null as soon as the child control process crashes. If you don't, and you navigate off the host window, and then back into the host window, or cause the application to repaint in any way, this BuildWindowCore() method will fire and fail.

You can try the following trick, BUT you will need to figure out the process in which the control is hosted. When you have the Process object, you can do this:

```
/* on a seperate thread, monitor the process */
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    ServiceHostProcess.WaitForExit();
    /* back to the UI thread */
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(ClearChildControl);
});
```

The `ClearChildControl` function in my case, simply clears the content to null, so a Repaint attempt wont even execute the `BuildWindowCore` function.

```
private void ClearChildControl()
{
    if (null == PlayerPanel)
        return;

    /* this border panel hosts the control of another process */
    PlayerPanel.Child = null;
}
```

Comment: For this was the main issue. I didn't clear all hosted childs to null. You saved my day Martin!

Answer (score 0):

As "ghord says, the error comes from `HwndHost.BuildWindow`, however you can avoid this by ensuring the HWND you provide is not `IntPtr.Zero`, and that it represents a window via:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

However if the process that provides the HWND crashes while you're servicing the call to `BuildWindowCore`, there's nothing you can do other than throw an exception or let the base class do it for you. To avoid crashing your application, handle `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` and set `Handled` to `true`.